# iptables - use different outgoing IP if destination is certain domain

Tags: iptables, routing, forwarding

I have a VM that has two IPs. Let's say 1.2.3.4 and 4.3.2.1.

If i do "ip a", it shows me 1.2.3.4 as first one and 4.3.2.1 as second:

```
2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1476 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/void
    inet 127.0.0.1/32 scope host venet0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 1.2.3.4/24 brd 1.2.3.255 scope global venet0:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 4.3.2.1/24 brd 4.3.2.255 scope global venet0:1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I think Linux will always try to do a connection to your destination with the first IP, you can see it if you ping something and have a higher latency to your destination if you use 1.2.3.4 instead of 4.3.2.1 (ping -I 4.3.2.1 destination).

Now I use applications where I sadly can not use a different interface or a source IP address like in ping or traceroute. So I have to say that if my VM wants to go to destination1.com (domain, not IP!), it should use 4.3.2.1 as source IP, instead of 1.2.3.4, because it has a better connection to destination1.com.

And if my VM wants to go to destination2.com, it should use 1.2.3.4 as source IP, instead of 4.3.2.1, because 1.2.3.4 has a better connection to destination2.com than 4.3.2.1.

Is it possible to reroute / forward traffic with iptables like this? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current setup will not work because you have two IP addresses allocated to one NIC. You need to turn your VM into a router (or gateway). Therefore you need to have at least two network interface cards assigned to this VM, with unique IP addresses on different subnets. (**venet0** = 1.2.3.4/24 and **venet1** = 4.3.2.1/24 for example)

First of all, enable ip forwarding on the Linux VM

```
$ sudo echo 'net.ipv4.ip_forward=1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

Route tables operate at Network Layer. Therefore hostsnames will not be applicable in this case. You must first convert target hostnames to IP addresses or subnet range.
Lets assume that the domain `destination1.com` owns the range of `172.16.10.0/24` and all traffic must exit through interface **venet0**:

```
$ sudo ip route add 172.16.10.0/24 dev venet0
```

While domain `destination2.com` owns the range of `192.168.20.0/24`, and traffic must exit via interface **venet1**

```
$ sudo ip route add 192.168.20.0/24 dev venet1
```

Once you are happy with your configurations, then consider [Persistent Routes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54745/gmyag.html).